# Redis: Can we XADD with ID in past timestamp relative to current time

Tags: redis

I want to save data with ID in past time relative to current time.

Example:

```
Last Id: (None)
Current Time: 1904878793327
```

Running:
`xadd test 1804878793327-1 test 123`

Will throws error, `ERR The ID specified in XADD is equal or smaller than the target stream top item`

Eventhough the inserted entries are none, i couldn't insert new entry with timestamp way further back relative to the current time.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with timestamps.

When the stream is created, you can use whatever id you like:

```
redis> DEL test
(integer) 0
redis> XADD test 2-2 a b
"2-2"
redis> XREAD STREAMS test 0-0
1) 1) "test"
   2) 1) 1) "2-2"
         2) 1) "a"
            2) "b"
redis> XDEL test 2-2
(integer) 1
```

However, additional items cannot be added with an id lower than or equal to the last id, even if that item was already removed from the stream:

```
redis> XADD test 1-1 c d
(error) ERR The ID specified in XADD is equal or smaller than the target stream top item
```

You can see that the last id is kept internally:

```
redis> XINFO STREAM test
 1) "length"
 2) (integer) 0
...
 7) "last-generated-id"
 8) "2-2"
...
```

This guarantees that a Redis stream always behaves as an append-only log.

Comment: You're right. So the confusion is because i have deleted a 'current' timestamp. Then when i try to insert past timestamp it always throws error. Thank you for the explanation.